# How to broadcast a message to a specific channel in all guilds?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot has made a channel named `quotient-private` in every server it is . I want to broadcast a message from my server to all those channels named `quotient-private` I have written the following code which doesn't throw any error , still doesn't work though

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.check(user_is_me)
async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
    channels = bot.get_channel("quotient-private")
    guild = bot.guilds
    for guild in guild:
        for channel in channels:
            try:
                await channel.send_message(channel, msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Also is their any way I can get this channel even if the server owners edit its name?

Answer (score 0):

To find the correct channel, you can use the [`get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get) method in your for loop:

```py
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command()
@commands.check(user_is_me)
async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        channel = get(guild.text_channels, name='quotient-private')
        if channel is not None:
            await channel.send(msg)
```

Also `Channel.send_message()` is the old `discord.py` method, now you have to use `Channel.send()`. With the `discord.py rewrite` update (after v1.0) a lot of methods changed.
If you have difficulties with what changed, you can look at the discord.py documentation → [Migrating to v1.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=migrating)